# How to change Swing application's look and feel at runtime?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, look-and-feel

I know that there's a `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(Component c)` method but it doesn't work perfectly. For example, I have a `JFileChooser` and the current look and feel is Windows, then I change the look and feel to Nimbus with `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(mainWindow)`, and the main window's style is changed correctly, but when I show the file chooser with the `JFileChooser.showOpenDialog(Component parent)` method, it's still in Windows look and feel. The same happens if I show a popup dialog with the `JPopupMenu.show(Component invoker, int x, int y)` method.

Any solution to this issue?

Comment: To be clear, you also adjusted the current L&F with [`UIManager.setLookAndFeel()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#setLookAndFeel%28java.lang.String%29)?

Answer (score 7):

Assuming that `value` is the class name of the new look-and-feel, here is the snippet to update all windows and sub-components:

```
public static void updateLAF(String value) {
    if (UIManager.getLookAndFeel().getClass().getName().equals(value)) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(value);
        for (Frame frame : Frame.getFrames()) {
            updateLAFRecursively(frame);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void updateLAFRecursively(Window window) {
    for (Window childWindow : window.getOwnedWindows()) {
        updateLAFRecursively(childWindow);
    }
    SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(window);
}
```

Comment: Which will not help if you cache a Swing component which is not part of the Swing hierarchy in your own code.

Comment: @Robin Indeed, nice catch for the cached components. Yet, if it is embedded in another component which is the hierarchy, another option is to override `updateUI`, call `super.updateUI` and also forward the call to the file-chooser.

Comment: I know this thanks to experience. Already spend some time on this problem in my own code. Typically for a file chooser it is not contained in the hierarchy, but only opened in a dialog when needed

Comment: `Window[] wins = Window.getWindows();` instead of` Window window : frame.getOwnedWindows()` could be works for all containers that could be `isDisplayable()`,  `isDisplayable(`) returns containers with removed `Rootpane` or if `DecorationsTyp`e is changed programatically

Comment: Updating all windows returned by `Window.getWindows()` doesn't affect my file chooser that has not yet displayed in a dialog.

Comment: @ZhaoYi Please also refer to Robin's comments: components that are cached and not part of the component hierarchy will not be updated. Yet, if your component is cached within another component which is part of the hierarchy, you could simply override `updateUI`, call `super.updateUI` and then forward the call to your cached component `updateUI()` method.

Comment: One problem is that some components are created from 3rd party libraries, and I'm unable to explicitly update its UI. And do you know how to add a listener to `UIManager` as pointed out by Robin?

Comment: @ZhaoYi Probably with `UIManager.addPropertyChangeListener` and watch for the change of property `"lookAndFeel"`.

Comment: It doesn't help if I can't get all references to components.

Comment: @ZhaoYi How can't you get references to some components but yet you manage to display those components? If you are absolutely unable to reach those components, then there is not much you can do except check that, once displayed, the components use the proper L&F and if not call updateUI()/updateComponentTreeUI.

Comment: Sure that's possible, e.g. a popup up menu created by a 3rd library, and is shown by `JPopupMenu.show`. In this case, how could I get the reference to that popup menu?

Answer (score 6):

Calling `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(mainWindow)` will only update the Swing components in the Swing hierarchy under `mainWindow`.

If you store the `JFileChooser` somewhere in your code (e.g. in a field of a class) without showing the `JFileChooser` the chooser will not be updated by the `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(mainWindow)` call. You can work around this by adding a listener to the `UIManager` yourself and call `SwingUtilities.updateComponentTreeUI(myStoredFileChooser)` from that listener when the look-and-feel is changed.

Make sure you do not create a memory leak with this, e.g. let that listener only have a `WeakReference` to the `JFileChooser` (as the lifetime of the UIManager equals the lifetime of the JVM)

Comment: How to add a listener to `UIManager`?

Comment: Great job on highlighting the `WeakReference`.

Comment: @ZhaoYi did you even bother to open the javadoc of the `UIManager` class. In that case I am sure you would have found the [`addPropertyChangeListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/UIManager.html#addPropertyChangeListener(java.beans.PropertyChangeListener)) method

Comment: As I've said below, some components may be created by 3rd party libs, thus I'm unable to get their references.